# Not able to upload public key to keyservers. Maven central repo upload fails

Tags: gnupg, sonatype, gpg-signature

I am trying to publish my repo to maven central repo. I uploaded my public key to :

1. http://keys.gnupg.net
2. hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com
3. hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net

I could even receive the response from them using 
*gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys XXXXXXXX*

But while uploading the repo to maven staging, I am getting below error

```
No public key: Key with id: (XXXXXXXXXXXXXX)was not able to be located on &lt;a href=http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/&gt;http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/&lt;/a&gt;. Upload your public key and try the operation again.[ERROR]     * No public key: Key with id: (XXXXXXXXXXXXXX) was not able to be located on &lt;a href=http://keys.gnupg.net:11371/&gt;http://keys.gnupg.net:11371/&lt;/a&gt;. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
```

I am not sure what is the mistake. 
Any help would be appreciated.

I am uploading public key from Windows10.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling and reinstalling the gpg4win app did the trick.